# Salvaging fir tree from armillaria root rot

Tags: fungus, rot, conifers

I am trying to salvage a fir tree from armillaria root rot. This would be its 3rd year of visible disease damage.

It says [here](https://gardeniaorganic.com/revive-a-dying-conifer/): "If your conifer is dying from evergreen root rot, shovel the moist dirt from around the roots and let them dry."

Should I give it a try or there is just no way to defeat armillaria fungus ?

If yes, to what depth, how close to / far away from the trunk, in what time of the year and for how long ? I should note that some 40% of this tree's roots are situated under a concrete alley that will not be dug up.

Thank you

---

Adding some photos. Not much damage to be seen since i have smeared it with that light gray paste. Also some pics of the armillaria outcrop on the drip line.
I am located in Bucharest, Romania, where the summer temperatures are often in the 35C - 40C range.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The information on that site is only true for some evergreens in some parts of the world.  What part of the world are you in and can you add a picture of the damage?

Comment: @kevinskio please see my addition

Comment: Are you sure it is _Armillaria_? I don't recognize that mushroom, but it doesn't look typical of _Armillaria_ species (small size, notched gills, no ring on stem). Unless you've seen them sprouting directly from the roots or stem, it is probably not a parasitic species.

Comment: @Eonema No I am not, but these four good reasons are pointing at it: other people have identified it as armillaria, the mushrooms are right on the drip line from that fir tree and nowhere else, foliage loss attern and not being succumbing after one year of treatment, trouble has started some years after one big tree in the adjacent yard fell to the ground. Unfortunately no one would come and see it in situ, only through photos.